# How to append to the beginning of an int in Python?

Tags: python, list, int, append

First of all, is it possible to append to an int ? If not I guess i'll have to convert it to a string first. I know how to append to a list
Anyways, how would you append a digit to the beginning of a number(instead of appending it to the end). Say number = 345, and you'd like to append super which is equal to 2 to the beginning of "number" to make it "2345".
How would you do it ?
To append it to the end of a list i'd use:

```
alist.append("hello")
```

Answer (score 2):

To "append" to numbers, you need to convert them to strings first with `str()`. Numbers are immutable objects in Python. Strings are not mutable either but they have an easy-to-use interface which makes it easy to create modified copies of them.

```
number = 345
new_number = int('2' + str(number))
```

Once you are done editing your string, you can easily convert it back to an int with `int()`.

Note that strings don't have an `append` method like lists do. You can easily concatenate strings with the `+` operator however.

Answer (score 1):

As @Fredrik comments, you can get from any integer to any other integer by a single addition - and this is how you should probably do it, if you deal with integers only.

```
>>> i = 345
>>> 2000 + i
2345
```

There are, however,  many way to express "prepend a 2 to 345", one would be to use [format](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format):

```
>>> '2{}'.format(345)
'2345'
```

Comment: I like the complexity of this answer where you show that `2000+345=2345` :-)